# about equal_func of unodered set/map

Tags: c++, std

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

class EQ {
public:
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) const {
        bool temp{ a.size() < b.size() };
        const string& shorter{ temp ? a : b };
        const string& longer{ temp ? b : a };
        return equal(shorter.begin(), shorter.end()
            , longer.begin(), next(longer.begin(), distance(shorter.begin(), shorter.end())));
    }
};

int main(){
    unordered_set<string, hash<string>, EQ> set;
}
```

I think EQ is the func that called in every emplacement, and check that key exist or not. But that EQ does not call for every each set.emplace(). How can I change the func of compare-equality-of-keys which would be called in emplacement?

Comment: If the hash is different there is no need to call `EQ`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah I understand the problem thankyou

Comment: @Caleth my intention  is if ```a``` is substr of ```b``` and at the beginning of b,--> a is same as b . so, I have to ignore the length of a and b. If I don't check the length, I heard that equal depend on length of two ranges of parameter first. am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unordered_set` uses buckets to store the values. A bucket may contain one or more objects. The bucket to store an object in is based on the value the hash function returns.

During a lookub (whether that's done for insertion or to check, if a object is already part of the set) `unordered_set` first determines the bucket based on the hash and then uses the equals function to check equality with every object in that bucket. If there are no objects in that bucket, there are no checks to be done with equals.

This is why a comparison may or may not happen on insertion or lookup. This is also why you need to make sure that 2 equal objects have the same hash.